# Tableau: Same source, multiple unrelated tables with separate visualization on same Dashboard

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, visualization, tableau-api

I am stuck with this problem, basically

- I have multiple tables in same data source (Hive)
- Each table will have its own visualization in Tableau
- And want have all these visualization on same dashboard
- These tables are unrelated and have different number of columns (So no union) and may have some of the column with same name (Country, date etc)
- Joining table wouldn't make sense as there is no common data across these tables
- Data is huge so cartesian or cross join wont help
- I have no control over the data that i stored in these tables in hive

I was looking for option in Tableau where

- I can create the visualization separately on each table separately and then somehow pull all these visualization in single dashboard but so far i am not getting any way to do this without combining these tables.

Any ideas on how i can achieve this?

Comment: Tableau workbook can have as many data connections as you like. Then each sheet can be your viz for that data source. Combine sheets onto a dashboard. As you state, there won't be any relation between them but nothing you describe would seem to impede this.

Comment: Exactly same thing i tried this morning and it worked. Thanks for the answer @Bernardo

Comment: I'm having same issue. Do I really need to create a new connection to my database for every single independent query I want to use to create the dashboard?